# AngularJS/jQuery at bottom of <body> not working on iPhone 5 iOS8.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, angularjs, ios8

For a few reasons, I'm loading AngularJS, jQuery and my scripts at the bottom of `body`.

This works fine on all the desktop browsers, as well as on iPhone 6, but not on iPhone 5 running iOS8.0. The libraries all load and I get no errors, but the scripts just don't work.

The crazy thing is that if I just move the libraries up higher in `body`, everything works fine.

I've (sort of) solved the jQuery issue — by not wrapping my script in `$(document).ready`, my scripts run OK.

But no luck so far with AngularJS. Anyone seen this before?

Update: No issue in iOS9 on iPhone 5 either.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely wan to load scripts outside js code. Keep in mind that the order of loading the scripts matter, specially if you have dependencies.

I would load the jquery first, then angular.js files and finally your js code. I've noticed that it's best for me if I put jquery and angular.js references in the header and my js files before the end of the body.

Comment: I've got everything in the right order. I know loading in body can cause issues, but it's been worth it for the performance boost. Plus, this is being called via WordPress shortcode and thus too late to load in head.